# match_constraint (0dp) hides view completely inside ConstraintLayout

Tags: android, layout, android-constraintlayout

I am trying to create a ConstraintLayout that consists of a CheckBow and a TextView. I'm trying to make the TextView's width 0dp and even though it looks correct on Android Studio, when I try it on the emulator or a device, the TextView part disappears and only the CheckBox remains.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/mainLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/checkBox"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:buttonTint="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:checked="false"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/checkText"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:text="testtext"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/checkBox"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Both should be visible and TextView's width should change according to its constraints.
I know this is not completely necessary here and I could use a LinearLayout, but I need to use this functionality in other parts of my application too, so I need to resolve this.

Comment: I ran it and it looks fine (shows "testtext").  Try setting a background color on your textview so you can see if the problem is in your code.

Comment: @BooberBunz thanks for taking the time, I have indeed tried setting a background color, but it doesn't show at all. I have also tried this inside an empty project, it seems to be working fine, I believe the problem is somehow that I am using it inside a custom view. Can you think of anything from a parent view that would affect the ConstraintLayout like this?